# Add links to images gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to link some gallery images to different external webistes. After some research I'm not able to found a solution that isn't using a plugin. Is this possible in wordpress without using plugins? I can't install plugins for this project so any suggestion will be appreciated thanks.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'name' => 'partners'
);
$logo_img = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="container-fluid" id="">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:1em;margin-bottom:1em;">
<?php if( $logo_img->have_posts() ): while( $logo_img->have_posts() ): $logo_img->the_post();
$logo_gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );
if( $logo_gallery ): ?>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
<?php foreach($logo_gallery as $logo ): ?>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="" width="60" id="partner-logo" style="margin:0 .5em 0 .5em;"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many images we are talking about, if these images are named you could use some logic to create a URL based on the name, if they are not named and there aren't that many, you could rename them.

Here's an example;

```
<?php
// If there is a matching string, set a specific URL
if (preg_match('/site1/',$logo)) { $set = "yes"; $link = "https://website1.com"; }
if (preg_match('/site2/',$logo)) { $set = "yes"; $link = "https://website2.com"; }
if (preg_match('/site3/',$logo)) { $set = "yes"; $link = "https://website3.com"; }

// If there is no matching string, set a default URL
if ($set !== "yes") { $link = "https://default.com"; }

// Now encase your image in a URL
echo "<a href='$link'>
<img class='img-fluid' src='$logo' alt='' width='60' id='partner-logo' style='margin:0 .5em 0 .5em;'/>
</a>";
?>
```

By the way, id='partner-logo' - the id should be unique.

Comment: the images are logos of various partners and aren't named, they will increase the number during the time so I don't think that I can use the approach you've suggested. The main problem is that I don't know if there is any hook or wordpress filter that I can use to add the links.

Comment: You need to add something unique to the images. If you can't rename them but they are referenced in a table, then add a text column to the table and put the corresponding URL for the image in that column.

Comment: It's a wordpress based website, I can't control what happen with tables or code at all.

Comment: Last try: find the images on your WordPress, they will have a unique name. Make a note of each image name and where they should be redirected to and then use my coding example.

Comment: I will try, but there are better approach that will not violate the DRY principle and are more wordpress friendly also if used in the loop.

Comment: If that's the case your initial post now seems misleading as you stated "After some research I'm not able to found a solution that isn't using a plugin.". If you have subsequently found better solutions, it would be wise to alert people of this. Good luck.